# Remote WCF Service

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, windows-services, remote-access

I build a WCF Windows Service and I want connect to it via Internet.
So I was looking for a suitable binding. I decided to use wsDualHttpBinding.

It is working so far if I use securityMode=None in my xml and ProtectionLevel=None in my ServiceContract.

Now I have the problem that I cannot secure the connection between my Service and my Client, because I don´t want anybody to see any details during my Login process.
When I use Message security and ProtectionLevel=EncryptAndSign I cannot access my Service.

Does anybody know where the problem is?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why do you need a duplex binding? Do you have callbacks?

Comment: Yes it is very important, because I have callbacks.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I am getting an Exception that my remote machine denies the access. And that the Client is not authorized.
Is it possible to have message security without any authorization ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally done,
after days of researches I found a suitable solution for my problem.

I decided to use a certificate mechanism. Now I am creating a certificate and I can use message security.

Yes, it was quite an overhead, but it works fine.

Comment: This helped me to create a certificate: http://blog.pluralsight.com/selfcert-create-a-self-signed-certificate-interactively-gui-or-programmatically-in-net

This helped me to create a certificate on the local machine which can be used by every user on this machine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231858/private-key-of-certificate-in-certificate-store-not-readable